# Form validation containing fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a simple form which I would like to check has valid data before submitting and saving the data.

However, due to `fetch(...)` being async, I cannot get the validation to stop and wait for the result.

Is there a way to stop the fetch from being async?
Or is perhaps a better way to do this?

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    fetch(`/check?id=${id}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        if (json.error) {
            // Prevent the submit here
            // event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: add `event.preventDefault()` before the call to `fetch()`. Without it there, the form is being submitted regardless of the fetch success or failure.

Comment: @RandyCasburn If the fetch doesn't return an error I would like the form to submit normally. Wouldn't your suggestion stop the form completely?

Comment: If the validation check is happening server-side anyway, why do it in two separate requests? You might as well do the validation at the same time as saving. If security and data integrity is important your "save" endpoint should always validate inputs on its own. Otherwise, someone can bypass your check endpoint and hit your save endpoint directly and corrupt data. Do you have control over the save endpoint?

Comment: After your client-side validation is successful, all you have to do is do `form.submit()`. That's it.

Comment: @DSander Yes, the check is server-side as well, so that is certainly an option. However, I wanted to make a more UI friendly method. Rather than always causing a page reload.

Comment: In that case, if you are only validating a single input (such as ID) then I would add an onfocusout() or onblur() listener for that specific input box which will call the check endpoint. Only show the submit button for the form if the validation passes.

Comment: @DSander Yes, that is exactly the solution I am after! Thank you so much. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No problem. I submitted as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a UI friendly experience you can add onfocusout() or onblur() listeners to each  field in the form, and validate each input as they are entered. You can disable the Submit button for the form by default, and only enable it when all validations have passed. Something like this:

```js
function validateId() {
 let id = document.forms.myForm.id.value;
 if(id === ""){
   document.forms.myForm.submit.disabled = true;
   return;
 }
 fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${id}/repos`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        if (json.error) {
          // fail validation
          alert("Failed!");
          document.forms.myForm.submit.disabled = true;
        } else {
          // success
          document.forms.myForm.submit.disabled = false;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
         alert("Error! " + error);
         document.forms.myForm.submit.disabled = true;
    });
 
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  ID: <input type="text" name="id" onfocusout="validateId()">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```